# Building a basic classifieds site and getting a Python SQLite error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to connect my Python code to my SQLite Database and I'm getting an error:

```
query_results = test.db ('SELECT * from STUFF where id="{}"'.format("iPhone"))
```

NameError: name 'test' is not defined

---

My Python code is as follows:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/search results")
def search():
query_results = test.db ('SELECT * from STUFF where id="{}"'.format("iPhone"))
"""
query_results like:
[ {"text" : cool phone" }
 {"text" : cool phone" }
 {"text" : cool phone" }
 {"text" : cool phone" }
]
"""
return render_template("results.html", query_results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

NOTE:

index.html is a search bar

results.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Hi!</title>
<!-- - CSS -->
</head>
<body>
{% for n in query_results %}
<li>{{n["date"]}}: <a href="/listing/{{n["url"]}}>{{n["text"]}}</a></li>
<!-- looks like <li>Jan 1: <a href="listing/123457">cool phone</a></li> -->
{% endfor %}    
</body>
```

Comment: It's telling you `test` is not defined. And it's not defined in the code you posted. Where is it defined?

Comment: Isn't it defined as: 

def search():